# How do I connect with dart community to suggest something?

Tags: android, iphone, dart

What I hope to do is tell something that I think is important to Dart community.
If somehow it was possible to code android and or iPhone apps using Dart that would be very awesome and same for Dart.

There is one path, that is making program in Dart compiling it to JavaScript and then making app using Adobe air.

But looks inefficient.

So is there any other way which I am unaware of, via which I can build an Android app at least? Using Dart I know you can build an app, using JavaScript and HTML/CSS. So I am looking for HTML + CSS + Dart.

It'd be cool if adobe air supports Dart language directly.

Answer (score 4):

great question! You can connect to the Dart community in a few ways.

- Discuss Dart with other community members and engineers at the [Dart mailing list](http://www.dartlang.org/mailing-list).
- File bugs and features requests in our public bug tracker: [dartbug.com](http://dartbug.com)
- Ask questions on Stack Overflow using the tag `dart`. :)

For news and updates, I suggest following:

- [new.dartlang.org](http://news.dartlang.org) for a blog style feed
- [+Dart](https://plus.google.com/109866369054280216564/posts) on Google+
- [@dart_lang](http://twitter.com/dart_lang) on Twitter

In you specific case, when you have a big idea like the one you are suggesting, I would recommend the mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Seth's comments. One other way of interacting with the Dart Community is the #dart channel on irc.freenode.net which you can access from any irc client (such as mIRC, xchat, etc), or from the [Freenode webclient](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=dart)

Answer (score 0):

Something to look at for using Dart to build phone apps, though it would still involve first converting to JS, is [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com). You're right: it would be cool if Dart were directly supported on more platforms, but it's really only one simple step to produce the JS from Dart.

To check out some of my own experiments with standalone iPhone web apps (games, of course) created in Dart, click [here](http://richthepandagames.com/DartAndArt/).

The short answer, then, is, yes: it certainly is possible to create apps for mobile devices with Dart, but, at least for now, it will probably involve clicking the "Generate Javascript" option in DartEditor somewhere along the line.

Comment: awesome hat you are already building such stuff...keep it going. Next step should using some of native capabilities: background services, camera/gps, redirecting calls. :D